# Simple integral substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got stuck proving that if $x=\tan\left(\theta\right)$ then
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(1 - x^{2}\right)^n\,{\rm d}x
={1 \over \sqrt 2}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{n+1}\left(\theta\right)\,{\rm d}\theta\,,
\qquad\Re\left(n\right) > -2
$$

Thank you !.

Comment: This equality is only true for $\Re(n)>-2$, so I added it to your post.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a difference of squares in an integral, it is often good to simplify the squares using the Pythagorean theorem. As $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$, we have $1 - \sin^2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta$. Now $1 - \sin^2\theta$ is a difference of squares, and looks a lot like our integral.

So we should really do the substitution $x = \sin\theta$. Doing this substitution yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (1 - x^2)^n dx &= \int_0^{\pi/2}(1 - \sin^2\theta)^n\cos\theta d\theta \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{n+1}\theta d\theta,
\end{align}$$
which is the corrected form you were looking for.